# Casting issue: java.lang.Number to gt Clojure

Tags: loops, clojure

I recently receive the error which is "ClassCastException clojure.core$num cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.gt" .

My implemented function called "getNumber" only gets an integer number.

Here is the my function called getLoop returns this error:

```
 (defn getLoop []
    (getNumber num)
    (loop [z num]
           (when (> z -1)
           (println z)
           (recur (- z 1)))))
```

On the one hand,  this query works correctly.

```
 (defn getLoop []
    (loop [z 3]
           (when (> z -1)
           (println z)
           (recur (- z 1)))))
```

I am wondering how I can avoid the error in the "getLoop" function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please show us `getNumber` source?

Comment: Sure I can, as I said this query is just a trivial function , in order to get this error. Here it is :  
(defn getNumber [num] (equals num 3)); equals it is just a macro implemented in the Ekeko Plugin.
If I run this function as (ekeko [num] (getNumber num)). The return value shows up like that : ([3])

Comment: in any case, it seems like you should write (loop [z (getNumber)]...) to bind the result to z on the first iteration

Answer (score 0):

The symbol num is not bound to the return value of `(getNumber num)` in your function body. Here is the function in more idiomatic Clojure:

```
(defn getLoop [num]
  (loop [n num]
    (when-not (zero? n)
      (println n)
      (recur (dec n)))))
```

If your `getNumber` returns a number as you said, it should be invokable like this:

```
(-> num getNumber getLoop)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `num` in `getLoop`, and thus `z`, are referring to [`clojure.core/num`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/num), which is a function that coerces its argument to a number. That's why the exception  says "clojure.core$num cannot be cast to java.lang.Number" - it's saying that the function `num` is being used in place of a number and that this isn't supported. This is happening because there's nothing in `getLoop` that would bind `num` to a different value.

I think you mean one of two possibilities:

```
;; First possibility
(defn getLoop [num]
  (loop [z num]
    (when (> z -1)
      (println z)
      (recur (- z 1)))))

;; Usage:
(getLoop (getNumber num))
;; Or:
(-> num getNumber getLoop)

;; Second possibility
(defn getLoop [num]
  (let [num (getNumber num)]
    (loop [z num]
      (when (> z -1)
        (println z)
        (recur (- z 1))))))

;; Usage:
(getLoop num) ;; (It calls `getNumber` internally)
```